# Issue on Overlaying Two Divs on Background of HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html, css

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/8F2G8/) and let me know why I am not able to overly the div `layer2` with yellow background on save level as other `layer1` and `Canvas`?

Here is the code I have:

```
<div id="canvas-wrap">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <div id="layer1"></div>
    <div id="layer2"></div>
</div>

#canvas-wrap {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:500px
}
#canvas-wrap canvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0
}
#layer1 {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-image: url('http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y443/Behseini/c1f7a913-898d-44aa-ad4a-c73a9cbc5823_zpsb0a0136c.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#layer2 {
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/8F2G8/8/) what you want? you have a position and z-index issue

```
#canvas-wrap {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:500px
}
#canvas-wrap #myCanvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
#layer1 {
    position: relative;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background-image: url('http://i1275.photobucket.com/albums/y443/Behseini/c1f7a913-898d-44aa-ad4a-c73a9cbc5823_zpsb0a0136c.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index:10;
}
#layer2 {
    top:0px;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris this is almost what I want but I need to have the Drawing on the canvas on the top of everyting. As you can see the image is behind the canvas

Comment: not sure what you mean.  in my fiddle you see the reggae man and the red dot in front of the yellow

Comment: yes but I need to have the red dot on top of every thing

Comment: As you can see the image is rendering after canvas

Comment: No worry I removed the Zindex from Layer1 and it is fixed now, once again thanks

Comment: sorry. z-index still.  [see updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MilkyTech/8F2G8/9/)

Answer (score -1):

It's because `#layer1` is consuming the space over the canvas. `#layer2` is pushing against the layer and can't move up.

So in order to have `#layer2` overlay, you'd need to set its `position:absolute;` and `top:0px`, as in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8F2G8/6/

Comment: Thanks TiltedListener, but as Chirs said you are missing first layer on your fiddle?

Comment: I misunderstood your question that you wanted the red circle on top.